# Ubuntu 20.04 - High GPU / CPU / FAN usage on Haswell-ULT

Tags: 20.04, graphics, google-chrome, cpu, gpu

I'm facing an issue and I can't figure out what to do.

When using the laptop in a minimal-normal way (chorme + slack) CPU rises a lot. Chorme seems to be the one consuming the most. Task Manager in chrome always has "GPU Process" in the top of memory. Sometimes, simple google sheets are in top of CPU usage, but youtube, Google Meet, or any animation makes it go high. Google meet backgrounds makes it worse. Just to give an idea of what causes the CPU to go up. Of course, this make that the fans go crazy, and it is pretty annoying to have fans running high 80% of the working time.

So, any ideas on what to look for? these are the laptop specs.

```
# System: Hewlett-Packard HP ENVY 14 Notebook
# Board: Hewlett-Packard 2289
# Kernel: 5.8.0-53-generic x86_64
# Memory: 16GB
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

I also have a 2nd 1920p monitor. Is this configuration too low to support 15 chrome tabs? and a youtube video?

Adding this info when using just chrome with youtube and giphy homepage.

- [System Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXL6w.jpg)
- [Gnome Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by7YB.jpg)
- [After setting more swap and removing Chrome extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfcbG.png)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `top` when the fans are spinning high. Also show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, there it is, just added it. Thanks!

Comment: You may have multiple problems. You certainly have a major RAM/swap problem. More on that later. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Have you installed any apps or extensions in Chrome, or is it box-stock?

Comment: @heynnema, Added the requested info. Chorme extensions yes, about 20 of them.. apps, not so many. Just a couple of google drive ones (sheets, docs)

Comment: Ah! OK... uninstall ALL of your Chrome extensions and apps. That might be difficult/painful, but Chrome is really causing a problem. I'll put together an answer about your RAM/swap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RAM/swap is a problem.

**Note**: You **may** have to add more RAM.

**Note**: Chrome **may** have a bad extension (you have 20 installed) or app installed, that's causing excessive CPU and memory/swap usage. Uninstall them.

In any case, your 2G /swapfile is too small. Let's increase it to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: Thanks!
At the beginning it seemed better, but quickly got up to high usage and fan party.

Is Swap enabled? how do I tell? 
This is the new free -h

`Mem:           15Gi       7,2Gi       3,4Gi       1,6Gi       4,9Gi       6,4Gi`

Swap:
`Swap:         4,0Gi          0B       4,0Gi`

Comment: also: should I re install Chrome? and the extensions? should they be kept away? I really use some of them

Comment: @pepepapa82 Swap looks good at 4G... but you must have done `free -h` shortly after booting, as swap used is zero. Without Chrome/extensions/apps... are you still having a fan party? When the fans get high, show me `top` again.

Comment: I'd say it fills lighter, but may be it's psychological. ha! I've added a screenshot of top when fan is running. Chrome still is the main owner of the consumption. Still Swap in zero though.

Do you think this might have something to do with Graphics Drivers?

Comment: Except for Chrome which is still a memory hog, `top` looks more normal. Have you reinstalled Chrome extensions/apps again? Swap was completely used up when you had a 2G /swapfile. Hopefully a 4G /swapfile will give a little more breathing room.

Comment: I've not reinstalled extensions yet.. I think it is as far as we can do.. But I'm still pretty impressed a 16GB RAM is not enough for just Chorme. That's why I thought this might have something to do with graph drivers. Thanks for all your quick answers!

Comment: @pepepapa82 I strongly suspect that one/more of your Chrome extensions/apps was causing the problem. The `top` command output looks normal now, and swap wasn't even being used at all... so 16G RAM appears to be enough to run Chrome now.